# Merge multiple video file in a file

Tags: java, android, video

I have multiple video recorded with same frame rate,and resolution.I want to merge both video to one video so result file will be large video.
I am using MP4 parser api and use below code -

```
Movie countVideo = new MovieCreator().build(Channels.newChannel(MuxExample.class.getResourceAsStream("/count-video.mp4")));
Movie countAudioDeutsch = new MovieCreator().build(Channels.newChannel(MuxExample.class.getResourceAsStream("/count-deutsch-audio.mp4")));
Movie countAudioEnglish = new MovieCreator().build(Channels.newChannel(MuxExample.class.getResourceAsStream("/count-english-audio.mp4")));
```

and using jar isoviewer-1.0-RC-35.jar. but it gives error in line -

```
Movie countVideo = new MovieCreator().build(Channels.newChannel(MuxExample.class.getResourceAsStream("/count-video.mp4")));
```

at build method.It says `The method build(String) in the type MovieCreator is not applicable for the arguments (FileChannel)`

Is there any issue of jar.So which jar i have to use.
Or any other way to do this.
Please help me in solve this point.

Comment: Please check this link also - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26404051/merge-multiple-video-in-android

Comment: have your problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

I did with two video files.

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    String filenamevideo = "f:/testvidfol/video.mp4"; //video file on your disk
    String filenameaudio = "f:/testvidfol/audio.wav"; //audio file on your disk


    IMediaWriter mWriter = ToolFactory.makeWriter("f:/testvidfol/videowriter.flv"); //output file

    IContainer containerVideo = IContainer.make();
    IContainer containerAudio = IContainer.make();

    if (containerVideo.open(filenamevideo, IContainer.Type.READ, null) < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cant find " + filenamevideo);

    if (containerAudio.open(filenameaudio, IContainer.Type.READ, null) < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cant find " + filenameaudio);

    int numStreamVideo = containerVideo.getNumStreams();
    int numStreamAudio = containerAudio.getNumStreams();

    System.out.println("Number of video streams: "+numStreamVideo + "\n" + "Number of audio streams: "+numStreamAudio );

int videostreamt = -1; //this is the video stream id
int audiostreamt = -1;

IStreamCoder  videocoder = null;

    for(int i=0; i<numStreamVideo; i++){
        IStream stream = containerVideo.getStream(i);
        IStreamCoder code = stream.getStreamCoder();

        if(code.getCodecType() == ICodec.Type.CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO)
        {
            videostreamt = i;
            videocoder = code;
            break;
        }

    }

    for(int i=0; i<numStreamAudio; i++){
        IStream stream = containerAudio.getStream(i);
        IStreamCoder code = stream.getStreamCoder();

        if(code.getCodecType() == ICodec.Type.CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO)
        {
            audiostreamt = i;
            break;
        }

    }

    if (videostreamt == -1) throw new RuntimeException("No video steam found");
    if (audiostreamt == -1) throw new RuntimeException("No audio steam found");

    if(videocoder.open()<0 ) throw new RuntimeException("Cant open video coder");
    IPacket packetvideo = IPacket.make();

    IStreamCoder audioCoder = containerAudio.getStream(audiostreamt).getStreamCoder();

    if(audioCoder.open()<0 ) throw new RuntimeException("Cant open audio coder");
    mWriter.addAudioStream(0, 0, audioCoder.getChannels(), audioCoder.getSampleRate());

    mWriter.addVideoStream(1, 1, videocoder.getWidth(), videocoder.getHeight());

    IPacket packetaudio = IPacket.make();

    while(containerVideo.readNextPacket(packetvideo) >= 0 ||
            containerAudio.readNextPacket(packetaudio) >= 0){

        if(packetvideo.getStreamIndex() == videostreamt){

            //video packet
            IVideoPicture picture = IVideoPicture.make(videocoder.getPixelType(),
                    videocoder.getWidth(),
                    videocoder.getHeight());
            int offset = 0;
            while (offset < packetvideo.getSize()){
                int bytesDecoded = videocoder.decodeVideo(picture, 
                        packetvideo, 
                        offset);
                if(bytesDecoded < 0) throw new RuntimeException("bytesDecoded not working");
                offset += bytesDecoded;

                if(picture.isComplete()){
                    System.out.println(picture.getPixelType());
                    mWriter.encodeVideo(1, picture);

                }
            }
        } 

        if(packetaudio.getStreamIndex() == audiostreamt){   
        //audio packet

            IAudioSamples samples = IAudioSamples.make(512, 
                    audioCoder.getChannels(),
                    IAudioSamples.Format.FMT_S32);  
            int offset = 0;
            while(offset<packetaudio.getSize())
            {
                int bytesDecodedaudio = audioCoder.decodeAudio(samples, 
                        packetaudio,
                        offset);
                if (bytesDecodedaudio < 0)
                    throw new RuntimeException("could not detect audio");
                offset += bytesDecodedaudio;

                if (samples.isComplete()){
                     mWriter.encodeAudio(0, samples);

        }
            }

    }

  }
}
```

Hope it will help u.

Comment: Thanks for you answer.Which jar i have to add for it.Can you please provide download link for it.

Comment: It also comes under same class  `com.xuggle.xuggler.ICodec.class`

Comment: finding some error while running code at line -IMediaWriter mWriter = ToolFactory.makeWriter(path+"videowriter.flv"); //output file.Please check my edited question

Comment: what is "ICodec.Type.CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO" in code and value it?

Comment: IAudioSamples samples = IAudioSamples.make(512, audioCoder.getChannels(), IAudioSamples.Format.FMT_S32); method make only 2 argument, but you have 3 argument. so it error

Answer (score 0):

The build() method uses String because it accepts the filepath, like

```
Movie countVideo = new MovieCreator().build(Channels.newChannel("c:/video/count-video.mp4"));
```