# Merge multiple Video In Android

Tags: android, video, xuggler

I just want to merge multiple video of same frame and resolutions.
I found below code  -

```
     String filenamevideo = "f:/testvidfol/video.mp4"; //video file on your disk
            String filenameaudio = "f:/testvidfol/audio.wav"; //audio file on your disk


            IMediaWriter mWriter = null;
            try{
                String mpath = path+"videowriter.flv";
                mWriter = ToolFactory.makeWriter(mpath); //output file
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            IContainer containerVideo = IContainer.make();
            IContainer containerAudio = IContainer.make();

            if (containerVideo.open(filenamevideo, IContainer.Type.READ, null) < 0)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cant find " + filenamevideo);

            if (containerAudio.open(filenameaudio, IContainer.Type.READ, null) < 0)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cant find " + filenameaudio);

            int numStreamVideo = containerVideo.getNumStreams();
            int numStreamAudio = containerAudio.getNumStreams();

            System.out.println("Number of video streams: "+numStreamVideo + "\n" + "Number of audio streams: "+numStreamAudio );

        int videostreamt = -1; //this is the video stream id
        int audiostreamt = -1;

        IStreamCoder  videocoder = null;

            for(int i=0; i<numStreamVideo; i++){
                IStream stream = containerVideo.getStream(i);
                IStreamCoder code = stream.getStreamCoder();

                if(code.getCodecType() == ICodec.Type.CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO)
                {
                    videostreamt = i;
                    videocoder = code;
                    break;
                }

            }

            for(int i=0; i<numStreamAudio; i++){
                IStream stream = containerAudio.getStream(i);
                IStreamCoder code = stream.getStreamCoder();

                if(code.getCodecType() == ICodec.Type.CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO)
               {
                    audiostreamt = i;
                    break;
                }

            }

            if (videostreamt == -1) throw new RuntimeException("No video steam found");
            if (audiostreamt == -1) throw new RuntimeException("No audio steam found");

            if(videocoder.open()<0 ) throw new RuntimeException("Cant open video coder");
            IPacket packetvideo = IPacket.make();

            IStreamCoder audioCoder = containerAudio.getStream(audiostreamt).getStreamCoder();

            if(audioCoder.open()<0 ) throw new RuntimeException("Cant open audio coder");
            mWriter.addAudioStream(0, 0, audioCoder.getChannels(), audioCoder.getSampleRate());

            mWriter.addVideoStream(1, 1, videocoder.getWidth(), videocoder.getHeight());

            IPacket packetaudio = IPacket.make();

            while(containerVideo.readNextPacket(packetvideo) >= 0 ||
                    containerAudio.readNextPacket(packetaudio) >= 0){

                if(packetvideo.getStreamIndex() == videostreamt){

                    //video packet
                    IVideoPicture picture = IVideoPicture.make(videocoder.getPixelType(),
                            videocoder.getWidth(),
                            videocoder.getHeight());
                    int offset = 0;
                    while (offset < packetvideo.getSize()){
                        int bytesDecoded = videocoder.decodeVideo(picture, 
                                packetvideo, 
                                offset);
                        if(bytesDecoded < 0) throw new RuntimeException("bytesDecoded not working");
                        offset += bytesDecoded;

                        if(picture.isComplete()){
                            System.out.println(picture.getPixelType());
                            mWriter.encodeVideo(1, picture);

                        }
                    }
                } 

                if(packetaudio.getStreamIndex() == audiostreamt){   
                //audio packet

                    IAudioSamples samples = IAudioSamples.make(512, 
                            audioCoder.getChannels());  
                    int offset = 0;
                    while(offset<packetaudio.getSize())
                    {
                        int bytesDecodedaudio = audioCoder.decodeAudio(samples, 
                                packetaudio,
                                offset);
                        if (bytesDecodedaudio < 0)
                            throw new RuntimeException("could not detect audio");
                        offset += bytesDecodedaudio;

                        if (samples.isComplete()){
                             mWriter.encodeAudio(0, samples);

                }
                    }

            }

          }
```

I have added jar in my build path-

```
1.log4j-1.2.16.jar
2.slf4j-simple-1.7.7.jar
3.slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar
4.xuggle-xuggler-3.0.660.jar
```

and below is my log cat error,when i run my code-

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.xuggle.ferry.FerryJNI.IBuffer_make__SWIG_0:(JLcom/xuggle/ferry/RefCounted;I)J
  at com.xuggle.ferry.FerryJNI.IBuffer_make__SWIG_0(Native Method)
  at com.xuggle.ferry.IBuffer.make(IBuffer.java:1088)
  at com.xuggle.ferry.FerryJNI.<clinit>(FerryJNI.java:21)
  at com.xuggle.ferry.JNIMemoryManager.setMemoryModel(JNIMemoryManager.java:1190)
  at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.<clinit>(MediaWriter.java:119)
  at com.xuggle.mediatool.ToolFactory.makeWriter(ToolFactory.java:149)
  at com.yps.demo.CameraRecordingActivity.mergeFiles(CameraRecordingActivity.java:84)
  at com.yps.demo.CameraRecordingActivity.onCreate(CameraRecordingActivity.java:69)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5141)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1150)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2315)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2420)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:165)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5387)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help me in solve this problem.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I recommend u to use JavaCV This will help you
https://github.com/bytedeco

Comment: Did you found something useful, i am searching for the same thing.

Comment: yes,after searching and some R&d i was found solution to my problem.